# Application freezes when freeing memory

Tags: c, windows, memory, malloc, free

I have the following code where I try to convert the string `03080000` into a byte array with the first byte being 03, second being 08, third 00, and fourth 00.

But it keeps freezing when i'm freeing the memory.
I tried stepping through it with a debugger (visual studio), but when I step over the free() function the debugger just seems to stop and it just hangs.

Am I corrupting `bData` by the way I'm writing to it? Or what could be wrong?

```
LPCWSTR lpValueData = L"03080000"
WCHAR HexChar[2] = {0};

UINT i;
UINT n = 0;

DWORD dwDataSize;
PBYTE bData;

dwDataSize = wcslen(lpValueData) / 2;
bData = (PBYTE) malloc(dwDataSize);
for (i = 0; i < dwDataSize * 2; i += 2)
{
    HexChar[0] = lpValueData[i];
    HexChar[1] = lpValueData[i + 1];

    swscanf_s(HexChar, L"%X", &bData[n++]);
}
// I want bData to be {0x03, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00}
// Compare bData to another byte array here with memcmp
free(bData); // freezes here.
```

Comment: Can't you use `strdup` or `wcsdup` ? And `malloc` should get `(dwDataSize * sizeof(WCHAR))`. And your code is not standard C, it is very Windows specific, so should be tagged as such (e.g. it won't compile on a Posix system, or on Linux).

Comment: Your `malloc` should get the number of bytes. I was wrong, you probably need at least `(dwDataSize+1) * sizeof(WCHAR)` and maybe even more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

L"%X" requested pointer to int, rather BYTE

So, it must be

```
int x;
swscanf_s(HexChar, L"%X", &x);
bData[n++] = x;
```